# Whether to use Jersey version 1.x or 2.0

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I wonder if anyone has an opinion as to whether to use the latest & greatest Jersey 2.0, or the most recent 1.x release (1.18, I guess). I am not interested to be on the bleeding edge of development, I just want something reliable. Is Jersey 2.0 a big enough improvement to use it instead of Jersey 1.18? Thanks for any light you can shed on this.

Comment: "Opinion"-based questions are not a fit for the Stack Overflow model. More: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Jersey 2, as of today, does not have the community integration (e.g. Guice, Spring) that Jersey 1.x has.

Comment: Imho this question shouldn't be closed, but probably just rephrased as "what are the differences between v1 and v2. There must be something substantial since the *major* version number went up."

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098341/how-do-i-migrate-from-jersey-1-0-to-jersey-2-0

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [release notes for Jersey 2.0](https://java.net/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10014&version=15271)  There are many improvements as you can see in that list.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: These links describes some of the changes: http://marek.potociar.net/2012/02/22/first-milestone-build-of-jersey-2-0/ or http://marek.potociar.net/2011/11/17/on-jax-rs-2-0-from-devoxx/